# Sales Order Confirmation Error

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to confirm the sales order but I am getting error shown below. The environment is updated from CU1 to CU9 recently. I did Full Compilation and Full CIL and Incremental CIL with out errors. Can you please suggest what could be the issue?
Thanks in advance.

```
Error : Map object not initialized.

Stack trace

(S)\Classes\FormletterService\postJournal - line 52
(S)\Classes\FormletterService\run - line 221
(S)\Classes\FormletterService\postSalesOrderConfirmation - line 14
(S)\Classes\DictClass\callObject
(S)\Classes\SysOperationServiceController\runOperation - line 93
(S)\Classes\SysOperationServiceController\runServiceOperation - line 22
(S)\Classes\DictClass\callStatic
(S)\Classes\SysDictClass\invokeStaticMethod - line 26
(S)\Classes\SysDictClass\invokeStaticMethodIL - line 39
(S)\Classes\SysOperationRPCFrameworkService\runServiceOperation - line 5
(C)\Classes\SysOperationServiceController\runOperationWithRunAs - line 7
(C)\Classes\SysOperationServiceController\run - line 22
(C)\Classes\FormLetterServiceController\run - line 3
(C)\Classes\SalesFormLetter\run - line 95
(C)\Classes\SalesFormLetter\main - line 138
(C)\Classes\FormFunctionButtonControl\Clicked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused because the `docuRefRecIdsPerJournalMap` variable of class `FormLetterService` is not initialized. Debug method `initDocuRefRecIdsPerJournalMap` where this variable gets initialized and also method `run` where the initialization method gets called. You may also have to check classes that extend from `FormLetterService` and overwrite any of these methods or change the `docuRefRecIdsPerJournalMap` variable. Also check if you have any customizations on these classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to 'Compile forward' the base class `FormletterService` and afterwards do a full CIL compilation again
Hope that helps